# Getting data from multiple sources in ListView.builder - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the ListView.builder constructor to build a list by retrieving data from Firestore.

I have two collections under which I have data in separate documents.

Collection Messages:

- Messages

  - message1
  - message2

Every document in message has the following keys: msgBody, sender. 
I store the sender id in the sender field in the message documents, which is actually the document name of the respective user in collection Users.

Collection Users:

- Users

  - james
  - greg

I am currently using the follwing code to read the messages collection and get the documents in it, then I get the value in sender field and create a document reference to the respective sender document and try to get the sender details using the Users document and use the data from the it in my list.

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Messages').snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          return new ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];  
                            DocumentReference tRef = Firestore.instance.document('/users/'+ds['sender']);
                            DocumentSnapshot tRefD;
                            tRef.get().then((tData){
                              print(tData.data); // I can see the sender data in the console here
                              tRefD = tData;
                            });

                             if (ds.data.isNotEmpty)
                             {
                              return Column(
                               children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(ds['sender']), 
                                  Text(tRefD['name']), //App crashes here works when I comment this line
                                ],
                              );
                           } 
                          }
          )
```

How do I read data from different documents under different collections and use it in the same ListView.builder?

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

By the time your user name is fetched, the UI had already been built. You either need to have a nested `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` one for each document. Or make your `async` calls in a separate method, call this method in your `initState` and populate the respective fields and then load them into the UI inside your `build` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was considering going with the nested StreamBuilder approach. Can you please give me an example of how to use a nested StreamBuilder within a StreamBuilder?

Comment: It is straight forward, the first StreamBuilder will return another StreamBuilder with `Firestore.instance.document('/users/'+ds['sender']).asStream`, and then build your `ListView`